# Which files are to be saved GitHub for an Android Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, egit

1.I am new to `GitHub` & working on an Android project. My question is, which files are to be saved/which not on `GitHub` for an Android project (Eclipse)?

2.How to delete that folder from `Github` using Eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325736/eclipse-android-and-gitignore

Answer (score -2):

copy this to your .gitignore file

# Built application files
   *.apk
   *.ap_

```
# Files for the Dalvik VM
```

*.dex

```
# Java class files
```

*.class

```
# Generated files
```

bin/
   gen/

```
# Gradle files
```

.gradle/
   build/

```
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
```

local.properties

```
# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
```

proguard/

```
#Log Files
```

*.log

for deleting that folder use these commands

```
git rm -r one-of-the-directories
git commit -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push origin master
```

or check this [solution]: [How to remove a directory from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository)

Comment: I cannot find these files & by the way forgot to include that I have accidently pushed all files  so how can I remove it from github.

Comment: that is a hidden file , which is located in the git folder, i,e it will be with README.md , if it is not created you have to create a file with .gitignore and paste that code and save it. from the next commit/push it will not show thous files for you, i have edited Answer, have a look , hope it is helpful for you..

Comment: Now I have added these folder & file names to  `.gitignore` as u said but how to delete that which I have already pushed? I mean how can I find which one's are which???

Comment: You can delete a file using delete button but you cannot delete a folder via web-interface. Only way to delete a folder from GitHub.com is to delete every file inside it.

Comment: or you can do that by using github windows. download github for windows and you have delete option in Windows application

Comment: I have github windows, installed but which folder should i delete? i cant find folders in answer written above!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57550/discussion-between-jax-l-and-rajesh-m).